# Faucets - No water

Tags: faucet

My bathroom sink had a leak. I turned off water under sink. It was off for a couple days. Now went to turn water back on and water isnt coming out of faucet. Neither hot or cold.

Comment: Is it cold where you are?  Could you have a new secondary problem, frozen pipes?

Comment: No water at all?

Comment: A little more info please. Tell us about the leak and what you did to fix it. Please give as much details as you can.

Comment: let the faucet 'run' for a minute, maybe there's just air in the pipe?